# Error ```Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.``` when try to login in admin

Tags: django, nginx, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

The error occurs only on the remote server. Locally everything is fine.
[image: 4:19]
[image: 4:20]
seems to be no problem with static
Didn't touch anything here:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]
```

Using: django, nginx, docker, git actions.
Where is trouble?

Another problem when I insert a link without an closed bracket (my-dns.com/admin) redirects me to 127.0.0.1/admin/ without port.
when link is fine, trouble with csrf token

Comment: whare the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting.

Comment: ALLOWED_HOSTS = [] There is empty

Comment: well, that's it, should include `'foodgram-fklska.hopto.org'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the CSRF-token is, well, to prevent cross-site request forgery (that s of course what the intend is).

So that means the CSRF middleware will also check the domain from which the request was made, these are the [**`ALLOWED_HOSTS`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std-setting-ALLOWED_HOSTS) in the `settings.py` file:

```
# settings.py

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['foodgram-fklska.hopto.org']
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you, but actually problem was in this constant```CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://*.foodgram-fklska.hopto.org/', 'https://127.0.0.1']```